# Getting mime type of file

Tags: php, mime-types

I'm trying to get mime type of the profile picture they're in format user_id.jpg or gif or png, I experimented with this code but it's not working.

```
function detectFileMimeType($filename='')
{
    $filename = escapeshellcmd($filename);
    $command = "file -b --mime-type -m /usr/share/misc/magic {$filename}";

    $mimeType = shell_exec($command);

    return trim($mimeType);
}

 function get_avatar($image, $user_id, $account) 
 {
   $imgurl ="http://mypage/files/pictures/picture-" . ($user_id, $mimeType) . ".jpg";

   if (!is_imgurl_good($imgurl)) {
     $imgurl = "http://mypage/sites/all/themes/simple_custom/user.png";
   }
   return $imgurl;
 }
```

Comment: Have you considered the [functions designed for this](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php)?

Comment: I took this code from the very page You provided.

Comment: You took it from the deprecated `mime_content_type()` page.

Comment: I tried this instead `$imgurl = glob("http://mypage/files/pictures/{*.gif,*.jpg,*.png}", GLOB_BRACE);` but not working

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the MIME type of a file fairly easily with built in functions provided by PHP -

```
function detectFileMimeType($filename='')
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type 
    $fileglob = glob($filename);
    echo finfo_file($finfo, $fileglob);
    finfo_close($finfo);
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: i dont know how to combine it into my existing code.. I need extension, for now it's hardcoded .jpg but some users have gif as well as png

Answer (score 0):

As well as `finfo` which works fine, a slightly easier method is to get PHP `getimagesize` function return, as this will return the MIME type as extracted from the file:

```
$file = "blah/blahblah/bubbles.jpg";
$fileTypeData = getimagesize($file);
$fileTypeData['mime'] = The Mime type of the image file.
```